# Application identity is not set exception all of a sudden

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm so confused.  I have been developing a VB.NET Windows Form in Visual Studio 2015.  Its been working great for years.  All of a sudden, my call to test if its network deployed when debugging throws:

*'System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException' in System.Deployment.dll*
*Additional information: Application identity is not set.*

This is the line that throws the error:

`If Not System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then`

I have two projects and one seems to work just fine.  I've poured over differences between the two projects and can find nothing.  I've poured over StackOverflow and google at large and I can't find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a blind shot in the dark here, but my immediate thought was permissions.  If you haven't changed anything, then perhaps something in the environment did.  And while you say you've compared them, did you look at all the other files that are part of the solutions but you didn't personally code?  The fact that it's referencing Application identity still makes me think permissions, though.  Are you signing?

Comment: Is this an _Exception Unhandled_ error or _Exception Thrown_ error (check the title of the error dialog)?  If it is a thrown type error, you somehow set the debugger to break when it is thrown (Exception Settings->Common Language Runtime Exceptions).

Comment: I agree with @technonaut. *Something*, *somewhere* has changed. This is almost a law of nature. The trick is to identify the change. I'd start with any client machine changes such as your user account, Windows version/updates, etc. Can you try a different machine/login? Also, try throwing all errors in Exception Settings and see if anything new pops up.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same issue you're having but this [MS link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/397c38e4-4306-4791-bed6-f319384c1086/application-identity-exception-when-trying-to-debug) seems into point to Debug Options as the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments/help.  I had a second machine to try and it worked just fine, so the issue was isolated to this specific project on a specific machine.  I took TnTinMn's suggestion and poured over the Exception Settings (in VS Debug->Window->Exception Settings, filter by InvalidDeploymentException).  On the working machine/projects, it was unchecked.  On the non-working machine/project it was checked.  I unchecked it, and all is back to normal now.  No clue how that randomly got set all of a sudden, but hopefully this helps someone in the future.